# Nielsen & Chuang, exercise 10.25 — Show $\sum_{y \in C}(-1)^{x \cdot y} = 0$ when $x \not\in C^\bot$

Tags: coding-theory

This question relates to exercise 10.25 of Nielsen & Chuang's [Quantum Computation and Quantum Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information).

---

Let $C$ be a linear code. Show that if $x \in C^\bot$, then
$$\sum\limits_{y \in C} (-1)^{x \cdot y} = |C| \quad \text{if } x \in C^\bot$$  otherwise, $$\sum\limits_{y \in C} (-1)^{x \cdot y} = 0 \quad \text{if } x \not\in C^\bot$$

---

**My attempt**

The fact that  $$\sum\limits_{y \in C} (-1)^{x \cdot y} = |C|$$ when $x \in C^\bot$ is rather very straightforward. $x \cdot y = 0$ by definition. Therefore we are summing $1$, $|C|$ times.

For when $x \not\in C^\bot$, the situation is not trivial at all. We know for some $y \in C$, $y \cdot x = 1$ (we can assume we are working over $GF(2)$). However, there are $y'$s for which $y' \cdot x =0$. Simply take $y'$ to be the zero binary string. It is plausible to think that we can form a partition such that
$$C_1 = \{y \in C | x \cdot y =0 \}$$
and
$$C_2 = \{y \in C | x \cdot y =1 \}$$
The part that I am struggling to show is that $|C_1| = |C_2|$ (I hope this is true). Can someone let me know how can I show $|C_1| = |C_2|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partition $C$ into pairs of the form $\{z,z+y\}$, where $y$ is that element of $C$ which has $y\cdot x=1$. One of the two elements of each pair is in $C_1$ and the other one is in $C_2$ because $(z+y)\cdot x= z\cdot x + y\cdot x = z \cdot x +1$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further please? We are taking the dot product here and $x \cdot y \neq x + y$.

Comment: @Josh Extended the answer.

Comment: If my answer still looks confusing, please feel free to ask for clarification until everything is clear.

Comment: Why "One of the two elements of each pair is in $C_1$ and the other one is in $C_2$" is true? You obtained $z \cdot x + 1$, but how do we know $z \cdot x + 1$ form an equivalent partition? For example. there could be more $z \cdot x + 1$ in $C_1$ than $C_2$. How do we know that is not the case?

Comment: The point of my calculation is that $z\cdot x$ and $(z+y)\cdot x$ are guaranteed to be different. So if $z\in C_1$, then $z\cdot x=0$, then $(z+y)\cdot x=1$, then $(z+y)\in C_2$; and vice versa, if $z\in C_2$, then $z\cdot x=1$, then $(z+y)\cdot x=0$, then $(z+y)\in C_1$. So the two members of the pair $\{z,z+y\}$ are always in the different subsets. So if we partition the whole $C$ into such pairs, and then send one member of each pair to $C_1$ and the other to $C_2$, we'll get $C_1$ and $C_2$ of equal size.